# Can you have more then one line in one DisplayAlert?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, popup, multiline

So i have this code and i was thinking about if you can have more then one line of text?

await DisplayAlert("Contact","Name: " + Contact.Fullname, "Close");

i allso want email and age to show

Comment: try using \n in the alert message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DisplayAlert("Contact","Name: " + Contact.Fullname + "\nAddress: " + Contact.Address + "\nEmail: " + Contact.Email + "\nAge: " + Contact.Age, "Close");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String contact_str = "Contact: " + name;
String email_str = "Address: " + email;
String age_str = "Age: " + age;
DisplayAlert(contact_str +"\n"+ email_str +"\n"+ age_str);
```